# Electric Bill Project

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting the program to not show any negative numbers and to stop at month 12.Ive tried changing the if statement and even adding another variable which was the balance before payment variable and I see no change in the program when it runs. Any suggestions?

```
    const double YEARLY_INTEREST_RATE = 22.24 / 100.0;    // 22.24% = 0.2224
const double MONTHLY_INTEREST_RATE = YEARLY_INTEREST_RATE / 12;
const double CREDIT_LIMIT = 500.00;     // credit limit
const int    MAX_MONTHS = 12;           // maximum months to display

int main()
{
    // Input values
    double balance = 495.75;
    double payment = 35.00;
    double charges = 0.00;

    // Computed values
    double interest;
    double newBalance;
    int month = 1;
    
    // table column headings
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setw(7) << "Month" << setw(9) << "Balance" << setw(10) << "Interest" << setw(9) << "Payment"
        << setw(9) << "Charges" << setw(12) << "New Balance" << endl;

    do {
        interest = balance * MONTHLY_INTEREST_RATE;
        newBalance = interest + balance + charges - payment;

        // display table values
        cout << setprecision(2);
        cout << setw(7) << month << setw(9) << balance << setw(10) << interest << setw(9) << payment
            << setw(9) << charges << setw(12) << newBalance << endl;

        month++;                // update month number
        balance = newBalance;   // transfer newBalance to balance for next computation

        if (payment >= balance)
        {
            newBalance = 0.00; 
        }
       
    } while (balance >= 0.00 && balance <= CREDIT_LIMIT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add examples of what you are getting and what you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop at month 12, use break with if code, as folliwing

```
    if (month == 12)break;
    month++;                // update month number
    balance = newBalance;   // transfer newBalance to balance for next computation
```

Comment: Thank you that worked

Comment: im still having trouble getting the program to stop at 0.00 once it gets into the negatives. I added a break but now it stops at the last positive number instead of showing 0.00. Any suggestions?

 if (newBalance < 0) break;

Comment: Actually, I'm not clear about your business problem. Can you mention it clearly?

Comment: sorry, nevermind i was able to get it but thanks for your help!